# bash script to find/grep particular string in xml files in particular folders

Tags: xml, perl, bash, unix

i have a problem at work, where i need to simplify the process how i searrh for logs. I would like to ask for help from experts here.

We have different services for every channel. The structure is following:

```
- root/channel_1/service_1/2014-05-21/file_54544654541.xml 
- root/channel_1/server2_2/2014-05-20/file_74272172.xml
- root/channel_1/service_3/2014-05-22/file_45456546.xml
- root/channel_2/service_4/2014-05-23/file_78754456.xml
- root/channel_2/service_5/2014-05-24/file_546546546.xml
```

my main problem is to find particular string in these xml files. Lets say, i know the channel name but i dont know the service name under which my particular string should be present. Also i know the date.

So in search i want to enter the channel name the date and string. The search would be going via all service folders and looking for string only in all xml files under particular date folder and particular channel.

any ideas for quickest and easiest solution to achieve this? Either by bash or perl?

Any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: So supposing you are working in one specific file: how would you grep in it? A normal `grep "mystring" yourfile` would make it or you need something more complex? In general, I think a little function can make it.

Comment: basically, my main objective here is to use find to search for string. when it will find the string in particular xml file, it will push in terminal the full xml file name, where it found the string i searched. I dont need to grep particular information from that xml file, i just have string(phone number) i want to find in which xml file this phone nr is present.Hope it's more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update (Now should manage problem in changing directory):
this is an example of how you can manage the problem of too many files.
If you save as `SearchForMe.sh`, after `chmod u+x SearchForMe.sh`, you can run it as

`./SearchForMe.sh 555-100006 2014-05-20 /log/root`

If you mind you can redirect the `STDERR` with `2>/dev/null` to avoid to see the errors and/or you can uncomment  the `exit` commands to make it stops on error.

```
#!/bin/bash

KeyToSearch=${1:-"555-123456"}
SearchDate=${2:-"2014-05-20"}
Starting_Path=${3:-"root"}
# echo "# Key  to search $KeyToSearch"   1>&2
# echo "# Date to search $SearchDate"    1>&2
# echo "# Starting  Path $Starting_Path" 1>&2
if ( cd $Starting_Path ) ; then  cd  $Starting_Path 
  else  echo "# Cannot start from the path " $Starting_Path ;  exit 3; 
fi

for d1 in */ ; do
  if ( cd $d1 ) ; then   # Nice trick: try to change in a subshell...
    cd  $d1; 
    for d2 in */ ; do
      if ( cd $d2 )  then
      cd "$d2"
        if [ -x "${SearchDate}" ]; then
          Cpwd=`pwd`
          echo "# Searching ${SearchDate} in $Cpwd "  1>&2   # you can comment this line
          grep -nH -e $KeyToSearch ${SearchDate}/*.xml | awk -v CDir=$Cpwd '{print CDir"/"$1}'
        fi
      cd ..
      else
        echo "Cannot change directory!" "$d1" "$d2"  1>&2  ;  # exit 2
      fi        # Uncomment the previous exit if you want to stop here
    done
  cd ..
  else 
    echo "Cannot change directory!" "$d1" 1>&2  ;             # exit 1
  fi            # Uncomment the previous exit if you want to stop here
done
```

Here the *trick* to try to change directory in a *subshell* `(cd $d1)` allows to manage the case in which there are no right of access in some directory.

To redirect the outputs(to answer a comment):
When you run a program or a script you can always redirect

- the standard output : adding at after the command and the options `1> My_Results.txt`
- the standard error: `2> My_Errors.txt`

You will have a file for Results and one for the Errors if it cannot enter in a directory, or read a file...

---

Old answer (when the number of files is not so big) 
Try something like

```
grep -E MYPATTERN -n root/channel_*/service_*/2014-05-24/file_*.xml
```

It depends from what you expect to find in your directory structure. 
I mean if all the directories are named service_1 ... service_9 without service_10 you can use `service_?` instead of `service_*` ...

`-E` Interprets PATTERN as an  extended  regular  expression and allow you a lot of selection rules
 `-n` print the number of the line in the files..

If you put in a script you can add variables where is needed.

Comment: Thank you Hastur, though im getting error:bash: /usr/bin/grep: The parameter or environment lists are too long.

Comment: Ok 1st try to understand if it is the parameter or the environment list that is too long. You can add `-f namefile` to obtain  patterns from FILE, one per line. You can write `ls root/channel_*/service_*/2014-05-24/file_*.xml | wc -l` to count the number of files.

Comment: i get the same for both commands advised  get for -f and ls wc -1: grep -E pattern-f /logs/xlogs/channel/*/2014-05-20/*.xml  bash: /usr/bin/grep: The parameter or environment lists are too long.  For ls /logs/xlogs/channel/*/2014-05-20/*.xml | wc -1 i get same error bash: /usr/bin/ls: The parameter or environment lists are too long.

Comment: You have too many files. :) I added an _example_ script in the hope you do not have too many files in each single directory.

Comment: Many thanks Hastur for your big help. I almost achieved what i wanted with your help! Only the issue i get is the error messages. I get needed results, but in these results i get also errors below:  bash-4.2$ ./search.sh STRING 2014-06-05 /logs/folder/folder1/channel/*/  i get ./search.sh: line 14: cd: */: A file or directory in the path name does not exist. ./search.sh: line 12: cd: 2014-05-31/: A file or directory in the path name does not  ./search.sh: line 14: cd: audit/: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action

Comment: i gave this data in search.sh > #!/bin/bash

KeyToSearch=${1:-""}
SearchDate=${2:-""}
Starting_Path=${3:- }

# echo "# Key  to search $KeyToSearch"
# echo "# Date to search $SearchDate"

cd $Starting_Path
for d1 in */ ; do
  cd "$d1"
  for d2 in */ ; do
      cd "$d2"
      if [ -d "${SearchDate}" ]; then
        Cpwd=`pwd`
        grep -nH -e $KeyToSearch ${SearchDate}/*.xml | awk -v CDir=$Cpwd '{print CDir"/"$1}'
      fi
      cd ..
  done
  cd ..
done

Comment: It seems it tries to enter in a directory and fails. So the unsafe (`cd ..`) bring the script to work in wrong directory and try to change where it cannot. I called it _example script_ even for this. 
Later I try to fix it.

Comment: thanks a lot! Seems to be working fine. it's a life saver for me. Works very fast. this is just a beginning what i want to achieve. basically i will try to modify it to connect to different box'es with same directory structure and search for string needed in all 6 servers. Do you have a quick hint, how i could output the sarch results from xml files to txt file based on your updated script? Also, would it be possible to have full text showed upon grep from the xml file as now it shows only 5-6 lines in command line.Thanks!

Comment: `Q2.` `>` : _Answered in the answer_. Now more clear. Check it. :) 
`Q1.`  Please create another question (make a link to this one if you believe): write with more space than in a comment, what do you mean for 6 boxes and how do you have access to those servers (if you see them like a directory, if you need `ssh` with passwords...).
`Q3` `grep` I didn't understand you sorry. Do another question (or in the same of Q1), and post some examples about what you have as current output  and what you would like to have instead. Close this one,accept one answer if you believe, upvote the useful ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find -path` as shown below:

```
find . -path "./root/${channel_name}/service*/${date}/*.xml" -type f -exec grep "${pattern}" {} \;
```

`channel_name` and `date` are variables holding the name of the channel (e.g. `channel_2`) and date (e.g. `2014-05-24`) respectively. `service*` searches all `service` directories.

Comment: thank you dogbane, but i'm getting error if i try to execute your query - find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to </.ssh>:
  : The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.

Comment: that means that `find` doesn't have permission to search inside the `.ssh` directory. Are you running my command from the directory which contains the `root` directory or from somewhere else?

Comment: apologies for confusion. there is log folder which is not in the root directory. i if i log in to box, i have logs, root, etc, tmp. the logs are kept in logs folder where i'm trying to use your command